# Jenkins fails building

Tags: git, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed on a VM running Windows 10.

I don't know how, but things were working fine, but yesterday things stopped working and this is why:

```
Started by user MyUser
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MyProj\workspace
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/myuser/MyProj.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/myuser/MyProj.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
FATAL: ssh executable not found. The git plugin only supports official git client http://git-scm.com/download/win
java.lang.RuntimeException: ssh executable not found. The git plugin only supports official git client http://git-scm.com/download/win
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.getSSHExecutable(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1569)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.createWindowsGitSSH(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1575)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1305)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:62)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:313)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:761)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1012)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1043)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1277)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
```

So there is an issue with the SSH executable... Has anybody seen this before?

#### About environment variables

I have been asked about the `PATH` envvar, well it was not set to the Jenkins folder and the SSH folder, so I did it. My `PATH` is pointing to:

```
PS C:\Users\myuser> echo $env:PATH
...;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\;C:\ProgramFiles\Git\usr\bin\;
```

Where folder `C:\ProgramFiles\Git\usr\bin\` contains `ssh.exe`.

Comment: Do you have ssh and git binary in your PATH?

Comment: Well I configured Jenkins by providing the Path to Git.exe, isn't that enough? And where am i supposed to find ssh.exe? Does it come with Git installation?

Comment: Btw I set those env vars and still does not work

Comment: I had the same problem. I'm kind of confused as to how this doesn't work out of the box with modern Jenkins 2.32 LTS, the latest Git Plugin, and the latest Git for Windows.The only thing that worked for me just now was to copy C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh to C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Comment: @jblaine me too. See the "update April 2017" section in http://stackoverflow.com/a/40903281/6309