# Jenkins not working anymore: SSH executable not found

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I don't know since when, but one day my Jenkins is not building fine my projects anymore.

- Jenkins 2.19.4
- Windows 10
- [Git client plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin) 1.19.0
- [Git plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) 2.4.0

#### The problem

I have configured Jenkins in order to build by connecting to my git repository.

```
Repository URL: https://github.com/myuser/MyRepo.git
```

When I try to build I get this:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: ssh executable not found. The git plugin only supports official git client http://git-scm.com/download/win
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:796)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ssh executable not found. The git plugin only supports official git client http://git-scm.com/download/win
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.getSSHExecutable(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1569)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.createWindowsGitSSH(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1575)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1305)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1273)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.getHeadRev(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2404)
    at hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig$DescriptorImpl.doCheckUrl(UserRemoteConfig.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:324)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:167)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:100)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
```

This can be seen also in the configuration page.

I searched the Internet and this is very frustrating, how is it possible that such a common problem has no stable repro and there is so bad documentation on this? Btw, what is going on?

Comment: Firstly, open command line under the same OS user, as Jenkins slave is running. Try to any `git` command. Number of ssh-utilities like `ssh-keygen` should be available. In case `git` is not available - check git installation on this machine

Comment: I can invoke `git` like `git --version` successfully

Comment: Also `ssh-keygen` is available in commandline

Comment: I have edited my answer to propose a workaround.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your [system path](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/) includes:

```
 <path/to/git>\usr\bin
```

You will find all the Linux executable (including ssh.exe) there.

You can install a [portable version of Git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) anywhere you want on your system.

---

Update April 2017: I had the same issue with Jenkins 1.614 and Git client 1.19

The only way I get past that error was by copying ssh.exe from `C:\myGit\usr\bin` (with C:\MyGit\usr\bin in %PATH%) to

```
c:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

Even though:

- There is not `Git` at all in `C:\Program Files` (I installed/unzipped it in `C:\myGit`), meaning after the copy, `C:\Program Files\Bin` only include `bin\ssh.exe`: that's it.
- `C:\Program Files\Bin` is *not* in the `PATH`.

But the Git Client (at least in that old version) is [hard-wired to search in that path](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/commit/b6fe319297b9ef5ceb29b260aa37c6cf994b414a).

Once I will switch to Jenkins 2.54+, I will test a more recent Git Client plugin.

Comment: That is already fine. I have `git` in my PATH. So this is not helping unfortunately :(

Comment: @Andry Not git: git\usr\bin: that is where the ssh and ssh-keygen executable are.

Comment: @Andry And make sure Jenkins is running with an account which does have that same path, not the system account.

Comment: I will try. I see now the difference though

Comment: So, `git\usr\bin` is in PATH. I will check users. So how can I see that a user has access to the same PATH?

Comment: Simply by adding a build step printing said path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129584/discussion-between-andry-and-vonc).

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the solution to this problem by following this method.

Manage Jenkins => Global Tool Configuration => Git -> Git installations.

Name: Default

Path to Git executable: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe

The problem was solved when I tried again by saying Save